# Get url code from RTMP

Tags: java, javascript, html, rtmp

I want to get url code to video from this site http://streamin.to/embed-1i758d4o9lsp-682x500.html

I watched this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8PuUnQCS7DQ) and used *Wireshark* and what I get

[
On screen: *Wireshark* TCP Follow on Handshake live
http://s16.postimg.org/mqvwt38ap/1_1.jpg ]

How to put this links together for valid video url link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image is too small but what you want is impossible, this *RTMP* vod service need two steps :

1. Connect to the RTMP server using the following URL :
   `rtmp://5.79.69.176:1935/vod?h=vgi7a4tp2luzcg3h5e7shtf2qthlmh3cv6g3d6gipwfep4oyo4idnrgjn7ra`
2. And then play the following stream :
   `98/8384638976_n?h=vgi7a4tp2luzcg3h5e7shtf2qthlmh3cv6g3d6gipwfep4oyo4ie3xojn7ra`

You can reproduce the video using a flash client (as [this one](http://jazzmatazz.free.fr/Cumulus/VideoPlayer/) for example).

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/mbvc6f5gd/ ########################Ops video won't open on http://jazzmatazz.free.fr/Cumulus/VideoPlayer/ I used this too http://www.wowza.com/resources/3.5.0/examples/LiveVideoStreaming/FlashRTMPPlayer/player.html and there connection failed

Comment: You're right. The links have already changed. In reality your site is more secure than I thought.
To get the current links to use just open the source code of the html page and search for the parameters "file" and "streamer". The first is the publication name and the second one is the rtmp link.
That's all!